# Hiding/Removing Quick Actions

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, list-view, quickaction

I am in Lightning and I am trying to remove an option from the quick actions of a list view for Task Object. The object settings on task isn't available for me to uncheck 'Delete' option on a profile and I don't see the option to remove it from the search layouts.

I would appreciate it if anyone can shed some light on this. 
I am not sure if this is a bug or limited feature.
[image]

Comment: Can you remove modify All from the given permission?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal - Do you mean modify all for Tasks? I couldn't find that in the object settings in the profile.

Comment: Modify ALL system permission... Its irrespective of Object